# Keeping just the rare characters in a long string

Tags: python, strings, programming-challenge

I'm working on [The Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/). The current code iterates over a 98,766-character string before printing an 8-character string. Current execution time is between 7 and 10 seconds.

How can I optimize my current code and what rookie mistakes am I making that may be adding to the execution time?

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = 'http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html'

x = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

text = (re.findall(r'<!--(.*?)-->', x, re.DOTALL))[1]

# source contains two adjacent html comments
# returns second comment

s = ''
for i in text:
    if text.count(i) < 10:
        s += i
print(s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is not a good variable name.  I suggest `page_source`.

Your approach is inefficient because you re-count all of the occurrences of each character, which is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), where *n* is the length of the string.

It would be better to use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  It's more efficient because counts all characters using just one pass through the string.  (We call that O(*n*).)

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(text)
s = ''.join(char for char in text if count[char] < 10)
print(s)
```

If you wanted to make your own counter with similar performance characteristics, you could do something similar to this:

```
count = {}
for char in text:
    count[char] = 1 + count.get(char, 0)
```

Comment: Yes, that's a considerable improvement.